# File upload validation

Tags: php, javascript, html, file-upload, validation

I should use the file uploads in a loop like,

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1"  id="form1"onsubmit="return(validate());">   
<?php for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)?>
<?php {?>
Select file:
<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="file<?=$i;?>" size="50" />
<?php }?>
<input type="hidden" name="ivalue" value="3" id="someVar"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

I have put some validations for file upload. Like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
var x=document.getElementById("someVar").value;
      for(i=0;i<x;i++) 
    {


     var filename=document.getElementById('file'+i).value;
     var extension=filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase();
     if(filename)
     {
         if(extension=='png' || extension=='gif' || extension=='jpg' ||extension=='jpeg') {
                return true;
            } else {
                alert('Allowed Extensions are "png","gif" and "jpg" !');
                return false;
            }
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         alert('Select upload files!');

         return false;
     }
    }

  }
</script>
```

But my script is only validating the first file only.( i know it's due to the id naming convention). But I need to validate, if the user doesn't select any of the files.How can I do that?I mean, How can I put validation for all files in the for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try generating IDs for file dynamically? Such as: id="file1", id="file2" ? And then loop the Javascript with getElementById("file" + i)?

Comment: I have put for loop which is edited in my code..but no change..am I miss something?

Comment: You have to use the [HTML5's File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Comment: Your function ends with "return true" when first file is verified.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("someVar").value;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)    {
        var filename=document.getElementById('file'+i).value;
        var extension=filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase();
        if (filename) {
            if (extension=='png' || extension=='gif' || extension=='jpg' ||extension=='jpeg') {
            } else {
                alert('Allowed Extensions are "png","gif" and "jpg" !');
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            alert('Select upload files!');
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document)
        .click(
                function() {

                    $("#uploadId")
                            .change(
                                    function() {
                                        var f = this.files[0];
                                        var p = f.size;
                                        var fup = document
                                                .getElementById('uploadId');
                                        var fileName = fup.value;
                                        var ext = fileName
                                                .substring(fileName
                                                        .lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                                        if (ext == "GIF" || ext == "gif"
                                                || ext == "jpg"
                                                || ext == "JPG"
                                                || ext == "jpeg"
                                                || ext == "JPEG"
                                                || ext == "bmp"
                                                || ext == "BMP"
                                                || ext == "png"
                                                || ext == "PNG") {
                                            if ((p <= 2097152)) {

                                                return true;
                                            }

                                            else {
                                                alert("Please upload the image max.size of 2 MB");

                                                $("#uploadId").val('');
                                                $("#uploadId").attr(
                                                        'enabled',
                                                        'enabled');

                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            alert("Please upload the images only");

                                            $("#uploadId").val('');
                                            $("#uploadId").attr('enabled',
                                                    'enabled');
                                        }
                                    });

                });
```